# MarkLogic Content Pump Java

Tags: java, maven, marklogic

I am trying to use the MarkLogic content pump from the maven dependency.

I'm struggling to find any documentation on the code. Does anyone have a tutorial they could point me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it eventually. What I was looking for was a way to use the mlcp maven dependency. The documentation I did find was mostly on how to use the content pump from command line and I need to use a java process instead.

The following link gave me the examples I needed on how to connect etc
http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/intro

Answer (score 1):

The [Using MarkLogic Content Pump chapter](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/content-pump#chapter) of the Loading Content into MarkLogic Guide documents how to work with MLCP. If that doesn't cover what you're looking for, please add more detail to your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is rudimentary maven information available here:

https://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp

If you are willing to use gradle, then you could use this in you build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven {url "http://developer.marklogic.com/maven2/"}
  maven {url "http://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/" }
}

configurations {
  mlcp
}

dependencies {
  mlcp "com.marklogic:mlcp-Hadoop2:1.3-2"
}

task importDocuments(type: JavaExec) {
  main = "com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump"
  classpath = configurations.mlcp
  args = ["import",
    "-host", "myhost",
    "-port", "9000",
    "-username", "usn",
    "-password", "pwd",
    "-input_file_type", "documents",
    "-input_file_path", "mypath"]
}
```

HTH!